# Firebase and React TypeError: firebase.auth(...).onAuthStateChanged is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use the onAuthStateChanged trigger to unsubscribe but I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , *firebase_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.getModularInstance)(...).onAuthStateChanged is not a function
> below is my Authcontext.js

```
import React ,{useEffect, useState ,useContext} from 'react';
import { auth } from '../api/firebase';
    
const AuthContext = React.createContext();    

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);        
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
    
    function register (email,password) { 
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }, []);
    
    const value = {
        currentUser,
        register,
    }
    
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
         </AuthContext.Provider> 
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json and the file where you are initializing Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not subscribing to the StateChange correctly , try the following

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { // detaching the listener
        if (user) {
            // ...your code to handle authenticated users. 
        } else {
            // No user is signed in...code to handle unauthenticated users. 
        }
    });
    return () => unsubscribe(); // unsubscribing from the listener when the component is unmounting. 
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error when I was working on react native app and because of firebase version change they have update some methods.

I have resolved this by below code and firebase verison is ^9.6.11.
you do not need to pull **onAuthStateChanged**

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

export const yourfunc = () => {   
 const auth = getAuth(); 
 auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
 console.log(user)
 } 
}
```